# Import File higher in folder tree

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to import a file (which kinda works as a map for the whole data folders I have) in my scripts.

The actual folder tree resembles of something like:

```
main
map.py
---/image
---/spectra
---/others
```

I want to call a function from `map.py` being in `/image`. I can't add the folder to `sys` since these scripts will have to work on different machines with different path to the main script folders.

What should I do? At the moment I'm fixing this by

```
cd .. 
import map.py as map
cd image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this before import statement can help

```
from os import path
import sys
sys.path.append(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in your shell to point at the folder containing `map.py`, wherever that may be.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/folder/  # This folder contains map.py
cd image
# Run your script that imports map
```

Using `PYTHONPATH` means you can locate `map.py` wherever you want, provided you set the environment variable in your shell before running the script.